# What does each byte in DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM store?

Tags: directx12

I'm studying DX12. I came across this texture format:

> **DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM**
> A four-component, 32-bit unsigned-normalized-integer format that supports 8 bits per channel including alpha.

It's not clear to me exactly - what values does each RGBA element store? As it is clear from the description above, these values are from 0 to 1 i.e. UNORM. But how, for example, can 1 byte R8 store a real number from 0.0f to 1.0f?

Answer (score 8):

The format modifiers like `_UNORM` / `_SNORM` / `_FLOAT`, etc... are documented on the [DXGI_FORMAT Page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dxgiformat/ne-dxgiformat-dxgi_format#format-modifiers):

> #### Format Modifiers
>
> Each enumeration value contains a format modifier which describes the data type.
>
> `_UNORM`
> Unsigned normalized integer; which is interpreted in a resource as an unsigned integer, and is interpreted in a shader as an unsigned normalized floating-point value in the range [0, 1]. All 0's maps to 0.0f, and all 1's maps to 1.0f. A sequence of evenly spaced floating-point values from 0.0f to 1.0f are represented. For instance, a 2-bit UNORM represents 0.0f, 1/3, 2/3, and 1.0f.

In your example format `DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM` there are 8 bits per channel, so 2<sup>8</sup> = 256 possible values (0-255).

Those will map to float values in the range 0-1 like the given example in the documentation:

```
Int Value          Float Value
0                    0 / 255 = 0.0f
1                    1 / 255 ≈ 0.00392156862f
2                    2 / 255 ≈ 0.00784313725f
3                    3 / 255 ≈ 0.01176470588f
...                ...
127                127 / 255 ≈ 0.49803921568f
128                128 / 255 ≈ 0.50196078431f
...                ...
253                253 / 255 ≈ 0.99215686274f
254                254 / 255 ≈ 0.99607843137f
255                255 / 255 = 1.0f
```

Comment: Thank you very much! As I understand it, this means that the texture itself stores R value from 0 to 255, G from 0 to 255, B from 0 to 255, A from 0 to 255, but these values in the shader are converted to R from 0 to 1, G from 0 to 1, B from 0 to 1, and A from 0 to 1. Did I understand correctly?

Comment: @black4 correct. The data is stored as an unsigned integer between 0-255 per channel. When sampled from a shader the resulting value per channel will be between 0.0f - 1.0f (as given by the mapping table above)

Comment: OK, thank you. I want to test my assumptions. For example, there is a format:

DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UINT

In the texture R has from 0 to 255, G has from 0 to 255, B has from 0 to 255, and A has from 0 to 255. And in the shader, R has from 0 to 255, G has from 0 to 255, B has from 0 to 255, A has from 0 to 255. Right?

Comment: @black4 correct :) And `DXGI_FORMAT_R16G16B16A16_UINT` for example can have a value from 0-65535 per channel, etc...

Comment: Thank you, @Turtlefight!

Comment: See [DirectXTex](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTex/blob/main/DirectXTex/DirectXTexConvert.cpp) for examples for all formats.